# Problem showing badges, ten on signature, nine on user page

Tags: support, badges

I have a weird "problem". Yesterday stackoverflow gave me two badges (I don't know which ones) rising to a total of ten. In the header and signature shows 10 but in the user page shows nine. It's not a big problem but it surprised me.

Can anyone tell me what's happening?

User name: Oscar Carballal

User page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/270293/oscar-carballal

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some errors in the new badge deployments that resulted in temporary duplicate badges which were retracted.

Your denormalized badge count will get fixed automatically when you earn your next badge.. so get on that! :)